Alt text defaulting to 'Thumbnail' on images
So I have been tasked with setting up SEO for our new website which is due to go live soon. I have had very little involvement with Drupal so hoping there is a simple setting I have missed.
I've spent some time setting up alt text for all images displayed on the site but when I inspect the pages img alt='thumbnail' is shown on all images which are contained within the class gallery images. Have searched for an answer for this but I'm unable to find anything related to this issue. I have been able to edit the Alt text for images stored within the body.
A couple images to show better than I can explain.. I was expecting the img=alt to show as Royal Eastbourne Green Book


So far I have tried clearing browser cache, incognito and different browser in case it was an issue with cached data, but not really sure where to go next as I feel I have done what I was supposed to have done. Thanks in advance.

Welcome to Drupal Answers :) It's impossible to answer this properly without access to the codebase, so you'll very likely need a developer to investigate. Most likely it'll be a bug in a theme (or module) template, or a theme preprocess function, something like that. But it'll almost definitely be a code issue and not solvable in the UI, unless you have an advanced system which allows you to assign variables to templates through the UI

@Clive Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to bring it to attention of a dev? Appreciate it's open source, just to make them aware not expecting an imminent fix.

It would be a bug in your specific application, not a bug in the Drupal project. The developers who created the site would be the best people to ask, or at least that's where you'd get the quickest answer

@Clive Ah okay I understand, thanks for your help.

I agree with @clive. On a default Drupal 11 install, an image field thumbnail, just after you upload an image, has an alt attribute with no value, which is different than this.
